# How to make form appear in all desktops of Windows 10 in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-10

I need to make a form visible even when I switch desktop on Windows 10 (by pressing `Ctrl-Windows-Arrow`) if possible, without any 2nd party lib

You can create multiple desktops by pressing `Windows-Tab` and clicking the `+` on the bottom-right corner.

Normally, a form only appears in the original desktop it was shown, and can be dragged to another desktop, but won't appear in multiples at the same time.

I know it's possible, because the splash forms of some applications do this. (Ex: Word, Excel)

I searched all over the web, but couldn't find a solution.

EDIT: Another app that I know that does this is the Task Manager, when you mark the "Always Show" checkbox.

Comment: I'm sorry do you mean dialog box? Like aForm.ShowDialog()?

Comment: @AmaoMao No, a form that is shown as Dialog only stays over the same application forms. I need a form shown in all the Win10 desktops.

Comment: Hi Luiz, did you solve this? I stil can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some help.  You have to dive into the world of AutoHotKey but this will solve your issues I'm pretty sure:

https://superuser.com/questions/950960/pin-applications-to-multiple-desktops-in-windows-10

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't know about this function in Windows 10, that I could right click on a window and pin it. But can I do this programmatically on VB.Net?

Answer (score 0):

Set your form's topmost property to true? Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried that before asking. No success. It only shows over other forms, doesn't keep the form visible when I switch desktops.

Comment: If that is the only form? And if you execute that exe?

Comment: It still doesn't appear in all desktops. I even tried a timer with Focus(), but the desktop just switches back to the one my form is